# Google cloud messenging for android

Tags: android, cordova

I've just started with Google Cloud Messenging with phonegap and I'm in an android virtual device.

For the client side app ,I chosed to go with this tutorial : https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova .
For the server side app ,I created a servlet containing the default code from google (see the last section) : http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

For the client app, I just want to make sure where to put exactly the sender id ,the tutorial say that i should place it where ever i find "your_sener_id" in the plugin file code ,but I cant find any string matching "your_sender_id".

-for the server side app,I have 2 little problems :
Here see a variable named "device" should i replaced it with the sender id too ?

```
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.*;

    Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);
    Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
    MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devices, 5);
```

-for "gcm-server.jar" ,I've tried to download it with sdk manager but the links i've added  could not be feched
.I tried also to download it directy from the net but my server wasn't happy with it

thanks for anyhelp and sorry for my bad english.